# How to put break delay after every 15 query execute

Tags: javascript

How do I put 5 minutes  delay after submit every 15 Query

so this is the javascript code I am using and it works fine.

But what I want is: 
I need to set a delay like of every 5 sec then execute the query, also after every 15 queries, needs to add a break for 5 minutes then continue  the execution

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/pKopwXp.gif' alt='loading...' />";

    // load() functions
    var loadUrl = "xxx.com/api.php?phone=xxxx&body=xxx";    
    $("#loadbasic").click(function(){
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);

    });
// end  
});

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: Read up about `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. They will let you accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: Plus you are clearly spamming phones with crap.

Comment: For break you can use setTimeout and for delay of of 5 second and execute query you can use setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` function returns an `id` which can be used to clear the call from the interval function, after passing the `id` to the `clearInterval` function. You can try something like this where I call a function after clicking a button **every 5 seconds** and keeping a `counter` variable on how many times the variable was incremented. If the `counter` is **5** then clear the interval and call the interval function after **10 seconds**. Script code is something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button").click(function() {
        intervalCall()
    })          
});

function intervalCall() {
  var counter = 0

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("Hello")
      counter++
      if (counter == 5) {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
      setTimeout(intervalCall, 10000)
    }
  }, 5000)
}
```

[JsFiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/a6jmnhz7/).